# How to watch for changes to HAML files and save them

Tags: haml, sass

I want to run a HAML command every time I save a particular file.  I know this can be done by compass but only for sass not HAML has anyone done this or guide me how to.

Answer (score 4):

On MacOS (and I assume, on linux too) you can use the 'watch' command from the terminal.

First, you need to install it using, for example "homebrew"

```
brew install watch
```

and then you can run it like:

```
watch haml haml/mypage.html.haml html/mypage.html
```

Answer (score 2):

Or if anyone stumbled in here like I did. There is a newer tool:  [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/) that does all these automatically and more.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, check out StaticMatic, nanoc, or Webby (search for these on gitHub). You can make them [work with Compass](http://wiki.github.com/chriseppstein/compass/) too.